# How to redefine action for power-button on NixOS?

Tags: systemd, nixos

How to define an action (i.e *sleep* or *hibernate*) that happens when power-button pressed?

I define actions for other events as follows

```
  services.upower.enable = true;
  services.upower.criticalPowerAction = "Hibernate";
  services.logind.lidSwitch = "hibernate";
```

Answer (score 1):

A quick search shows this article https://nixos.wiki/wiki/Logind.

As they mentioned there:

> `logind` handles power and standby hardware switches.

From what I see this article seams valid and the info is actual. You didn't mentioned what you are trying. I suspect you what disable your power key?

```
 services.logind.extraConfig = ''
    # don’t shutdown when power button is short-pressed
    HandlePowerKey=ignore
  '';
```

Update: I had a typo in the code snippet above. Thank you @sidharth arya for pointing that out.

Comment: Tried that, unfortunately it doesn't work. Seems like some other service listens to this button.

Comment: also @zzeroo please add '' after equals and before ; to make it work